# Regex - No repeation of period and comma and hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

I am trying to create a regex for addresses.

I currently have `[a-zA-Z0-9-\\.\-\,\\-\s\n]`, but it matches the repeating period, repeating hyphen, and repeating comma.  Is there any way I could limit the count of comma, hyphen, and period to 1?

It should match  `"5432 Lorem St. Tokyo, Japan 1234-54"`

and it shouldn't match `"5323 Dolor Ave... Kyoto,,,, Japan 555-33----33"`

Comment: Perhaps `^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+(?:[.,-][a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)*$`

Comment: Which language or regular expression engine are you using?

Comment: @cxw i am creating one for javascript

Comment: So, try `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\s]+(?:[.,-][a-zA-Z0-9\s]+)*$/.test(str)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Hi, Your answer is perfect but is there any way to allow seperate comma,dot,hyphens so long as they arent beside each other?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it should also match 'Lorem Ipsum Bldg., Quisia , Tokyo City, Japan'

Comment: Try `/^(?!.*([.,-])\1)[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,-]+$/.test(str)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew How am I going to mark this as the answer? Thanks alot!

Comment: I posted an answer, my WiFi connection is very poor at this hotel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disallow a repeated character from the set of "comma", "dot", or "hyphen", you can use a negative lookahead anchored at the start:

```
/^(?!.*([.,-])\1)[a-zA-Z0-9\s.,-]+$/.test(str)
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?!.*([.,-])\1)` lookahead checks if there is a repeated comma, dot or hyphen (see `([.,-])\1` - a capturing group followed with a backreference) and fails the match if found.

Also, to disallow partial matches, the anchors - `^` for start of string and `$` for the end of string - are necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9-\.-\,\-\s\n][a-zA-Z0-9-\.-\,\-\s\n][^a-zA-Z0-9-\.-\,\-\s\n]
```

is long-winded, but will match a single one of those elements that doesn't (`^`) have another one on either side of it.  Does that do what you want?

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

`^([a-zA-Z0-9\s\n]|(([\.,-])(?!\3)))*$`

So this matches any string that only contains any number of letters, numbers, spaces or line spaces OR periods, commas, or hyphens that are not immediately followed by itself.